# Non parametric test to compare variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, variance, nonparametric

I have two samples of same size but at least at one of them is not normal distributed (tested by Shapiro-Wilk-test). How can a compare the variances of theses samples? Especially, I want to know the p-value for the hypothesis: $\sigma_1^2 \leq \sigma_2^2$.

Comment: Although this is a duplicate question, unfortunately the answer in the duplicate thread is (woefully) incomplete.  For a common, effective, flexible solution to your problem, see https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35a.htm (about the Levene test).

Comment: As I understand the Levene test, it tests for equality. So there is no implementation in R which would solve my problem directly?

Comment: Your problem tests for equality, too.  If that's unclear, then check out our threads on (a) hypothesis testing and (b) one-tailed vs. two-tailed tests.

Comment: @user294892 Permutation tests are a problem unless you assume the locations are equal. You could get somewhere working with deviations from the mean. Alternatively, there's bootstrap testing. (But testing assumptions of other procedures to choose what test to use - all done on the same data - is generally not a great idea.)

Comment: What would be a better way? I only have 20-40 obervations per data set. So splitting the set doesnt make much sense for me.